# Склонение слов (место события, неодушевленное) (морфология)

Tags: php, морфология

В базу из соответствующего поля заносится какое-то место проведения работ, например: `склад`, `подвальное помещение`, `ресторан`, `кафе`, `чердак`, `поликлиника` и т.д.

В документе это место выводится как «... по своевременному проведению работ в `склад` по адресу:...».

А нужно «... по своевременному проведению работ в `складе` по адресу:...», «... по своевременному проведению работ в `подвальном помещении` по адресу:...», «... по своевременному проведению работ в `ресторане` по адресу:...».

Я дилетант в PHP, только учусь, и ничего лучшего не придумал, как задавать какую-то маску для сравнения возможных вариантов и если нет ничего похожего, то выводить то, что было вписано в поле:

```
function d_typeplace_morf($d_typeplace)
{
    $d_typeplace = mb_strtolower($d_typeplace);
    if ($d_typeplace === 'ресторан') :  echo 'ресторане';
    elseif ($d_typeplace === 'кафе') : echo 'кафе';
    elseif ($d_typeplace === 'столовая') : echo 'столовой';
    elseif ($d_typeplace === 'склад') : echo 'складе';
    else : echo $d_typeplace;
    endif;
}
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи в этом вопросе.

Comment: заведите таблицу в базе, где каждая строка будет содержать один термин, а каждый столбец разные формы этого термина (именно термина, так как "подвальное помещение"). Все. Дальше просто в шаблонизаторе (я надеюсь у Вас есть шаблонизатор?) придумайте способ вывод, например, через какую то функцию, которая будет получать нужное слово и форму. И все.

Comment: Понимаю, спасибо. А какой-то бесплатной наработки для автоматического перевода слова или фразы в предложный падеж не подскажете?

Comment: предложный падеж? ох, давно я русскую грамматику не смотрел. Можно думаю написать немного регулярок, но нужно ли это?

Comment: http://phpmorphy.sourceforge.net/dokuwiki/

Comment: https://htmlweb.ru/json/service/inflect?inflect=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4

Comment: Но словосочетания так так себе [получаются](https://htmlweb.ru/json/service/inflect?inflect=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Нужно сначало просклонять [Подвальное](https://htmlweb.ru/json/service/inflect?inflect=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5), а потом [помещение](https://htmlweb.ru/json/service/inflect?inflect=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Урл на [ресурс](https://htmlweb.ru/service/sklonjator.php)

Answer (score 0):

Предложу прототип офлайн решения, которое основывается на пакете [pymorphy2](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/guide.html) для python.

Решение упрощенное, но которое можно развить в рабочее и надежное.

1. Установить пакет ​`pip install pymorphy2`
2. Создать скрипт `morph.py` и сделать его исполняемым `chmod a+x morph.py`. Содержимое скрипта:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pymorphy2
import sys

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
p = morph.parse(sys.argv[1])[0]
print(p.inflect({'sing', 'loct'})[0])
```

3. Создать php-скрипт `foo.php` и сохранить его в папку с питоновским скриптом. Содержимое скрипта:

```
<?php
$morph = "python " . __DIR__ . "/morph.py";
$ww = [
    "склад",
    "подвальное помещение",
    "ресторан",
    "кафе",
    "чердак",
    "поликлиника"
];
foreach ($ww as $w) {
    $tt = explode(" ", $w);
    $r = [];
    foreach ($tt as $t) {
        $r[] = rtrim(`$morph $t`);
    }
    echo implode(" ", $r) . "\n";
}
```

4. Запустить скрипт: `php /path/to/folder/with/foo.php`